# Promote only a selected artifact file

Tags: jenkins

We have a build project which always generates three files (artifacts). When promoted, these files will be used for a setup package. With the promoted builds plugin, it's only possible to promote all artifacts of a build. Is there a way to only promote selected files of a build? Currently I can only think of splitting up the build process into separate projects - but then we've the problem with different workspaces.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The [**Promoted Builds plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) by itself does not "promote" the artifacts. It promotes a build run.

Part of the promotion process may be a [**Copy Artifacts step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), and that is the step that takes the artifacts from promoted build run and does ... whatever you have configured for the promotion.

In the Copy Artifacts step, you can definitely specify a pattern for the files to copy.